# Ruby on Rails and onchange

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I got this code for a small calculator:

```
<%= form_tag calculators_path, :method => :post, :remote => true do %>
<%= text_field_tag :data %> = <span id="sum"></div>
<% end %>
```

Can someone tell me how i can add the JS/Ajax onchange command to it, so the calculator automatically shows the result?

Sorry for that newbish question, im a total beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

:)

```
<%= form_tag calculators_path, :method => :post, :remote => true do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :data, nil, :onkeyup => "this.form.sub.click()" %> = <span id="sum"></span>
  <%= submit_tag "ok", :name => "sub" %>
<% end %>
```